# HTML file drop for local use

Tags: jquery, html, node-webkit

I am using node webkit to create an app. I would like to be able to drop files in a target element - just so I may get the filenames and not trigger an upload. Is this possible? how do I do this?

I am currently using https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop.

Comment: There's a page in the docs specifically for that https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Dragging-files-into-page

Comment: Thanks. That helped. I was looking at jQuery for the solution. If you put this as the answer, I shall be happy to mark it so. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from the [wiki](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Dragging-files-into-page):

```
// prevent default behavior from changing page on dropped file
window.ondragover = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false };
window.ondrop = function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false };

var holder = document.getElementById('holder');
holder.ondragover = function () { this.className = 'hover'; return false; };
holder.ondragend = function () { this.className = ''; return false; };
holder.ondrop = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  for (var i = 0; i < e.dataTransfer.files.length; ++i) {
    console.log(e.dataTransfer.files[i].path);
  }
  return false;
};
```

is one option, as well as the HTML5 file reader approach:

```
holder.ondrop = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0],
      reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event) {
    console.log(event.target);
  };
  console.log(file);
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  return false;
};
```

It's definitely important to note that the `path` field is included, as opposed to regular browsers where it is not available.